# How do I show the column and row numbers when printing a matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print the row and column numbers at the top and left when printing a matrix. For example, I want this:

```
test = [[7,7,7,7],[7,7,7,7],[7,7,7,7]]
```

to be shown as

```
     0 1 2 3
   0 7 7 7 7
   1 7 7 7 7
   2 7 7 7 7
```

The matrix prints fine with

```
for x in test:
    print(*x)
```

I just don't know how to format it correctly so as to show the index numbers. I found the answer here before but, sadly, I seem to have lost the URL to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate to provide indices when looping through an iterable:

```
for idx, x in enumerate(test):
    print(idx, *x)
```

For the first line you could do this (I hope the formatting turns out correct, can't test it I'm currently on the go):

```
print(" ", *range(len(test)))
```

When your matrix contains numbers of variable length, you can look into string formatting to print them as fixed-width strings. Here for example :
[How do I make a fixed size formatted string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837017/how-do-i-make-a-fixed-size-formatted-string-in-python)

Comment: Yup, this works. I don't know what I'll have to move around to make it work with double-digit numbers but your solution works for single digits perfectly.

Comment: Oh, good catch. You're right, when the numbers become variable length you need to invest extra effort. You would do this with string formatting, I linked a relevant question.

Comment: Just wanna point out one does not need to listify the range to be able to unpack it, i.e. `print(" ", *range(len(test)))` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `pandas`:

```py
>>> pandas.DataFrame(test)
   0  1  2  3
0  7  7  7  7
1  7  7  7  7
2  7  7  7  7
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw something similar with Numpy and it works too. It's just that I'm not allowed to use libraries, unfortunately.